# How many parameter in an RNN?

Tags: rnn

I came across this question asking about the number of parameters in an RNN layer, from my understanding it is the number of weights and biases, which in this case is **five**. Can someone confirm this?[image: Screenshot of question]

Question: **How many parameters are there in this RNN (i.e. weights and bias values)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, when counting the number of parameters in a neural network, you are referring to the total size of the matrices, not the number of matrices.

With the given data, we have that:

- $U \in \mathbb{R^{4\times3}}$ → 12 parameters
- $W \in \mathbb{R^{3\times3}}$ → 9 parameters
- $b \in \mathbb{R^3}$ → 3 parameters
- $V \in \mathbb{R^{3\times2}}$ → 6 parameters
- $c \in \mathbb{R^2}$ → 2 parameters

Totalling 32 parameters ( = 9 + 12 + 3 + 6 + 2).